# Responsive div : Side-by-Side div with same height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show side-by-side 3 div for responsive, but the content is different from each other. So I tried with below code, But not working for me.

The code is below

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GTT6H8OFHT3Q

```css
.col-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 16px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>


  <h2>Equal Height Columns</h2>
  <p>Make the columns match the height of the tallest column.</p>

  <div class="col-container">
    <div class="col" style="background:orange">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col" style="background:yellow">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>Hello World! 1</p>
      <p>Hello World! 2</p>
      <p>Hello World! 3</p>
      <p>Hello World! 4</p>
      <p>Hello World! 5</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col" style="background:orange">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
      <p>Some other text..</p>
      <p>Some other text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Looking for the example Link is [Paylocity](https://www.paylocity.com/who-we-serve/company-size/) Website.**

Can you please suggest to design the same with html code?

Comment: Why it does not works for you? What is your output? For me it works perfectly.

Comment: @MetropolisCZ responsive not working. Check the Paylocity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a super-cut-down version where the only CSS is a simple flex display, which is probably what you want to use as it resolves your height issue.

```css
.col-container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Equal Height Columns</h2>
<p>Make the columns match the height of the tallest column.</p>

<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col" style="background:orange">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col" style="background:yellow">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Hello World! 1</p>
    <p>Hello World! 2</p>
    <p>Hello World! 3</p>
    <p>Hello World! 4</p>
     <p>Hello World! 5</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col" style="background:orange">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
    <p>Some other text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Due to the display size of the code widget, I'll pop this in separately...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-container {
    display: block;
  }

  .col {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also set `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container to keep it in `display: flex` and have the possibility of making several levels with different col sizes, like Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Would adding the following query work for you as below the 352px there is an overflow

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 352px){
  .col {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also avoid using % units of width and try implementing the grid using fraction units for easy responsiveness i.e in our case 1fr 1fr 1fr